# Why the ref button will be clicked 3 times?

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple react component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Hello extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Hello Freewind</h1>
      <div>
        <button ref="button1" onClick={() => alert('1')}>Click 1</button>
        <button ref="button2" onClick={() => alert('2')}>Click 2</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={this._clickBoth.bind(this)}>Click both</button>
      </div>
    </div>;
  }

  _clickBoth() {
    this.refs.button1.click();
    this.refs.button2.click();
  }
}

export default Hello;
```

When you click on the "Click both" button, the "Click 1" and "Click 2" button will be clicked programatically. The strange thing is, I will see 6 alerts:

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
```

Which should be

```
1
2
```

But if I remove either line of `_clickBoth`, say, remove `this.refs.button2.click();`, it will behaive correctly and only show one alert:

```
1
```

You can see and try the project here: https://github.com/js-demos/react-ref-demo

Comment: Can you setup a demo on jsfiddle or something?

Comment: I have reproduced the problem. Interesting, indeed.

Comment: Another weird thing is that the `click` events accumulate exponentially depending on the number of refs you simulate the event on.

Comment: Yet another weird thing is that the `_clickBoth` handler gets called multiple times. Five times with two buttons, and two times with one button. Which is extra weird since that doesn't match the number of simulated clicks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what's wrong, but I'd definitely like to find out the technicalities behind it.

In the meantime, if you're looking for a way to fix it, you can wrap the buttons' click inside `setTimeout`, like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.refs.button1.click();
  this.refs.button2.click();
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also not sure what is going on, but I added a console.log to the `_clickBoth` handler and got the following result:

```
click both
click both
click both
1
2
1
click both
click both
2
1
2
```